# How is the ば form being used in this sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension, conditionals

> 他人への暴力を振るってしまうこともあれば、自傷行為にもなり、平常時ではありえないことを行ってしまう場合もある。

If you end up resorting to violence against other people, it will also result in self harm, and cases where you end up doing things unthinkable in normal times?
and

> 遊馬が次に瞼を開いた時、眼前に広がっていたのは真っ白な天井だった。

> 瞼を開くことができるまでの時間は途方もなく長かったように感じれば、刹那のように短かった感覚もある。

"If the time up until the point I'm able to open my eyes feels like it's long, it also feels like short?"

This is narration for context.

Comment: https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%B0%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%82-mobamo-meaning/

Answer (score 1):

It is for enumerating things. [Daijisen entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B0/#jn-172830):

> 3 ㋐（口語で仮定形に付いて）共存する事柄を並列・列挙する意を表す。「野球もすれ―テニスもする」「きれいな空もあれ―澄んだ空気もある」

For the first sentence, it is *there are times the person ends up ..., and at other times in self harm ...*.

For the other one, it is meant as *I felt... and at the same felt the duration was very short*. But to me, using ば is a little odd here. I'd expect 長かったようにも感じたし for example.